# [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have this odd issue with a trigger for my game.

I get the following error but I cannot see what the issue is.

> "2019-03-13 14:30:01 err=-1, [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]**Subquery returned more than 1 value.** `This is not permitted` when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression., SQL STATE: 21000, NATIVE ERROR: 512 (0x200)
>
> 2019-03-13 14:30:01 ::SaveCharacter 1144 Lexii ret=1, qerr=-1, {?=call Usp_Save_Char_Quest_Add_E(1144,2222,0,0,0,0)}"

```
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[Perfect_OJ]    Script Date: 13/03/2019 13:11:06 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Perfect_OJ]
   ON  [dbo].[CharQuests]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @QuestID INT = (SELECT QuestID FROM inserted)
    
    IF @QuestID = 2222 -- The Perfect Orange Stats QuestID
    BEGIN
        
        DECLARE @CharID INT = (SELECT CharID FROM inserted)
        DECLARE @UserUID INT = (SELECT UserUID FROM Chars WHERE CharID = @CharID)
        
        DECLARE @ItemType TINYINT,
                @RecRuneItemID INT
        
        DECLARE @StatRecRuneItemID TABLE (StatRecRuneItemID INT) -- Str, Dex, Rec, Int, Wis, Luc
        DECLARE @VitalRecRuneItemID TABLE (VitalRecRuneItemID INT) -- HP, MP, SP
        DECLARE @GearTypes TABLE (GearTypes TINYINT) -- Gears, Capes and Shields
        DECLARE @WeaponTypes TABLE (WeaponTypes TINYINT) -- Weapons and Accessories
        
        -- The above tables were created in order to ensure a fast access to the types
        -- of items that are to be recreated and the rune used to recreate them.
        
        
        SET @ItemType = (SELECT Type FROM UserStoredItems WHERE UserUID = @UserUID AND Slot = 0)
        SET @RecRuneItemID = (SELECT ItemID FROM UserStoredItems WHERE UserUID = @UserUID AND Slot = 1)
        
        INSERT INTO @StatRecRuneItemID VALUES (100230),(100231),(100232),(100233),(100234),(100235)
        -- ItemIDs of stat recreation runes (Str, Dex, Rec, Int, Wis, Luc, HP, MP, SP)
        
        INSERT INTO @VitalRecRuneItemID VALUES (100236),(100237),(100238)
        -- ItemIDs of vital stat recreation runes (HP, MP, SP)
        
        INSERT INTO @GearTypes VALUES (16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(24),(31),(32),(33),(34),(35),(36),(39),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(22),(23),(40),(72),(73),(74),(76),(77),(87),(88),(89),(91),(92),(96),(97)
        -- Types of gears, capes. Here you can include anything you want to be rerollable with both stat and vital stat recreation runes.
        
        INSERT INTO @WeaponTypes VALUES (16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(24),(31),(32),(33),(34),(35),(36),(39),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(22),(23),(40),(72),(73),(74),(76),(77),(87),(88),(89),(91),(92),(96),(97)
        -- Types of weapons, accessories. Here you can include anything you want to be rerollable only with stat recreation runes.
        
        IF ((@ItemType IN (SELECT GearTypes FROM @GearTypes)) AND (@RecRuneItemID IN (SELECT StatRecRuneItemID FROM @StatRecRuneItemID) OR @RecRuneItemID IN (SELECT VitalRecRuneItemID FROM @VitalRecRuneItemID))) OR (@ItemType IN (SELECT WeaponTypes FROM @WeaponTypes) AND (@RecRuneItemID IN (SELECT StatRecRuneItemID FROM @StatRecRuneItemID)))
        -- The above IF statement checks if the item to be recreated and the recreation rune are compatible with each other.
        -- As you can see, it works only if it's an item with the Type from @GearTypes(gears, capes) and all recreation runes,
        -- or if it's an item with the Type from @WeaponTypes(weapons, accessories) and stat recreation runes only.
        BEGIN
            
            DECLARE @Craftname VARCHAR(20),
                    @Str TINYINT,
                    @Dex TINYINT,
                    @Rec TINYINT,
                    @Int TINYINT,
                    @Wis TINYINT,
                    @Luc TINYINT,
                    @HP TINYINT,
                    @MP TINYINT,
                    @SP TINYINT,
                    @Enchant TINYINT,
                                
                    @ItemID INT,
                    @ReqWis TINYINT,
                    @Server TINYINT,
                    @OJs TINYINT,
                    @NewOJs TINYINT,
                    @MaxedOJs TINYINT,
                    @LowestOJType VARCHAR(3),
                    @LowestOJ TINYINT
            
            SET @Craftname = (SELECT Craftname FROM UserStoredItems WHERE UserUID = @UserUID AND Slot = 0)
            SET @Str = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,1,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @Dex = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,3,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @Rec = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,5,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @Int = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,7,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @Wis = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,9,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @Luc = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,11,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @HP = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,13,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @MP = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,15,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @SP = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,17,2) AS TINYINT)
            SET @Enchant = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Craftname,19,2) AS TINYINT)
                        
            SET @ItemID = (SELECT ItemID FROM UserStoredItems WHERE UserUID = @UserUID AND Slot = 0)
            SET @ReqWis = (SELECT ReqWis FROM PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items WHERE ItemID = @ItemID)
            -- Get the maximum possible OJ on the item
            SET @Server = (SELECT Server FROM PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items WHERE ItemID = @ItemID)
            -- Get the maximum amount of OJs on the item
            
            DECLARE @AllOJs TABLE (StatName VARCHAR(3), Stats TINYINT)
            INSERT INTO @AllOJs VALUES ('Str',@Str),('Dex',@Dex),('Rec',@Rec),('Int',@Int),('Wis',@Wis),('Luc',@Luc),('HP',@HP),('MP',@MP),('SP',@SP)
            -- Declaring the @AllOJs table and storing the OJs of the item before the recreation process.
            
            SET @OJs = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @AllOJs WHERE Stats > 0) -- Getting the amount of OJs
            SET @MaxedOJs = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @AllOJs WHERE Stats = @ReqWis) -- Getting the amount of MaxedOJs
            
            IF (@OJs <= @Server) AND (@MaxedOJs < @Server)
            -- Checking if there's still room for another perfect OJ.
            BEGIN
            
            DECLARE @NewStr TINYINT,
                    @NewDex TINYINT,
                    @NewRec TINYINT,
                    @NewInt TINYINT,
                    @NewWis TINYINT,
                    @NewLuc TINYINT,
                    @NewHP TINYINT,
                    @NewMP TINYINT,
                    @NewSP TINYINT,
                    @NewEnchant TINYINT
                    
                    -- Declaring the new variables, where the new orange stats will be stored
                    
            SET @NewStr = @Str
            SET @NewDex = @Dex
            SET @NewRec = @Rec
            SET @NewInt = @Int
            SET @NewWis = @Wis
            SET @NewLuc = @Luc
            SET @NewHP = @HP
            SET @NewMP = @MP
            SET @NewSP = @SP
            SET @NewEnchant = @Enchant
                
                -- Assigning the old OJs to the new OJ variables
                
                IF @RecRuneItemID = 100230 -- STR Rec Rune
                BEGIN               
                    SET @NewStr = @ReqWis
                END
                
                ELSE IF @RecRuneItemID = 100231 -- DEX Rec Rune
                BEGIN               
                    SET @NewDex = @ReqWis
                END
                
                ELSE IF @RecRuneItemID = 100232 -- REC Rec Rune
                BEGIN               
                    SET @NewRec = @ReqWis
                END
                
                ELSE IF @RecRuneItemID = 100233 -- INT Rec Rune
                BEGIN               
                    SET @NewInt = @ReqWis
                END
                
                ELSE IF @RecRuneItemID = 100234 -- WIS Rec Rune
                BEGIN               
                    SET @NewWis = @ReqWis
                END
                
                ELSE IF @RecRuneItemID = 100235 -- LUC Rec Rune
                BEGIN               
                    SET @NewLuc = @ReqWis
                END
                
                ELSE IF @RecRuneItemID = 100236 -- HP Rec Rune
                BEGIN               
                    SET @NewHP = @ReqWis
                END
                
                ELSE IF @RecRuneItemID = 100237 -- MP Rec Rune
                BEGIN               
                    SET @NewMP = @ReqWis
                END
                
                ELSE IF @RecRuneItemID = 100238 -- SP Rec Rune
                BEGIN               
                    SET @NewSP = @ReqWis
                END
                                
            END 
            
            ELSE GOTO FAIL
                        
        END -- End of the case where both items are good and compatible with each other
        
        ELSE GOTO FAIL
        -- In the case where the item and the rec rune aren't compatible with each other,
        -- the process will end. No modifications to the item will occur.
        
        CHECKOJAMOUNT:
        -- This label checks if after the reroll there aren't more
        -- types of orange stats than the item can normally have.
        
            DECLARE @NewAllOJs TABLE (StatName VARCHAR(3), Stats TINYINT)
            INSERT INTO @NewAllOJs VALUES ('Str',@NewStr),('Dex',@NewDex),('Rec',@NewRec),('Int',@NewInt),('Wis',@NewWis),('Luc',@NewLuc),('HP',@NewHP),('MP',@NewMP),('SP',@NewSP)
            -- Declaring the @NewAllOJs table and assigning the new OJs to it.
            
            SET @NewOJs = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @NewAllOJs WHERE Stats > 0)
            -- Getting the amount of OJs on the item after the reroll.      
        
            IF @NewOJs > @Server
            -- If the amount is bigger than what the item can normally have,
            -- the lowest stat, that is bigger than zero of course, is going to be removed.
            -- e.g. If the item allows max 4 orange stats, max stat being 40,
            -- it has 40 STR, 40 DEX, 40 REC, 39 LUC, and we want to use a HP Rec Rune on it.
            -- After the reroll process it will have 4000 HP, 40 STR, 40 DEX, 40 REC and 0 LUC.
            BEGIN               
                SET @LowestOJType = (SELECT StatName FROM @NewAllOJs WHERE Stats = (SELECT MIN(Stats) FROM @NewAllOJs WHERE Stats > 0))
                -- Getting the lowest stat.
                                
                IF @LowestOJType = 'Str'
                    SET @NewStr = 0
                ELSE IF @LowestOJType = 'Dex'
                    SET @NewDex = 0
                ELSE IF @LowestOJType = 'Rec'
                    SET @NewRec = 0
                ELSE IF @LowestOJType = 'Int'
                    SET @NewInt = 0
                ELSE IF @LowestOJType = 'Wis'
                    SET @NewWis = 0
                ELSE IF @LowestOJType = 'Luc'
                    SET @NewLuc = 0
                ELSE IF @LowestOJType = 'HP'
                    SET @NewHP = 0
                ELSE IF @LowestOJType = 'MP'
                    SET @NewMP = 0
                ELSE IF @LowestOJType = 'SP'
                    SET @NewSP = 0
                -- Whichever the lowest stat is, it is changed to 0.
            END
        
        CRAFTNAMEUPDATE:
        -- This label is responsible for applying the new orange stat to the item.
        
            DECLARE @FinalStr VARCHAR(2),
                    @FinalDex VARCHAR(2),
                    @FinalRec VARCHAR(2),
                    @FinalInt VARCHAR(2),
                    @FinalWis VARCHAR(2),
                    @FinalLuc VARCHAR(2),
                    @FinalHP VARCHAR(2),
                    @FinalMP VARCHAR(2),
                    @FinalSP VARCHAR(2),
                    @FinalEnchant VARCHAR(2)
                    -- As Craftname is a varchar(20), we need to create it out of varchars.
            
            SET @FinalStr = CAST(@NewStr AS VARCHAR(2))
            SET @FinalDex = CAST(@NewDex AS VARCHAR(2))
            SET @FinalRec = CAST(@NewRec AS VARCHAR(2))
            SET @FinalInt = CAST(@NewInt AS VARCHAR(2))
            SET @FinalWis = CAST(@NewWis AS VARCHAR(2))
            SET @FinalLuc = CAST(@NewLuc AS VARCHAR(2))
            SET @FinalHP = CAST(@NewHP AS VARCHAR(2))
            SET @FinalMP = CAST(@NewMP AS VARCHAR(2))
            SET @FinalSP = CAST(@NewSP AS VARCHAR(2))
            SET @FinalEnchant = CAST(@NewEnchant AS VARCHAR(2))
            -- Assigning the new OJs to the respective varchar(2) variables.
            
            IF LEN(@FinalStr) < 2
            BEGIN
                SET @FinalStr = '0' + @FinalStr
            END
            
            IF LEN(@FinalDex) < 2
            BEGIN
                SET @FinalDex = '0' + @FinalDex
            END
            
            IF LEN(@FinalRec) < 2
            BEGIN
                SET @FinalRec = '0' + @FinalRec
            END
            
            IF LEN(@FinalInt) < 2
            BEGIN
                SET @FinalInt = '0' + @FinalInt
            END
            
            IF LEN(@FinalWis) < 2
            BEGIN
                SET @FinalWis = '0' + @FinalWis
            END
            
            IF LEN(@FinalLuc) < 2
            BEGIN
                SET @FinalLuc = '0' + @FinalLuc
            END
            
            IF LEN(@FinalHP) < 2
            BEGIN
                SET @FinalHP = '0' + @FinalHP
            END
            
            IF LEN(@FinalMP) < 2
            BEGIN
                SET @FinalMP = '0' + @FinalMP
            END
            
            IF LEN(@FinalSP) < 2
            BEGIN
                SET @FinalSP = '0' + @FinalSP
            END
            
            IF LEN(@FinalEnchant) < 2
            BEGIN
                SET @FinalEnchant = '0' + @FinalEnchant
            END
            -- The above 10 blocks are here to ensure that each orange stat varchar(2) is actually 2 digit long.
        
            UPDATE UserStoredItems
            SET Craftname = @FinalStr + @FinalDex + @FinalRec + @FinalInt + @FinalWis + @FinalLuc + @FinalHP + @FinalMP + @FinalSP + @FinalEnchant
            WHERE UserUID = @UserUID AND Slot = 0
            -- The above block updates the Craftname of the item.
            
        DELETERUNE:
        -- This label removes the recreation rune.
        -- As you can see, it removes just one recreation rune, not the whole stack.
        
            UPDATE UserStoredItems
            SET Count = Count-1
            WHERE UserUID = @UserUID AND Slot = 1
            -- Decrementing the amount of recreation runes
            
            DELETE FROM UserStoredItems
            WHERE UserUID = @UserUID AND Slot = 1 AND Count = 0
            -- If after decrementing the amount of recreation runes the amount is 0, delete the row from the database. 
        
    END
    
    FAIL:
    -- This label is called from above a couple of times,
    -- in case the recreation requirements aren't met.      
    DELETEQUEST:
    -- This label deletes the recreation quest.
        DELETE FROM CharQuests
        WHERE CharID = @CharID AND QuestID = @QuestID

END

`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this! hope this will solve your problem.

```
DECLARE @QuestID INT = (SELECT QuestID FROM inserted)

        IF @QuestID = 2222 -- The Perfect Orange Stats QuestID
        BEGIN

            DECLARE @CharID INT = (SELECT CharID FROM inserted)
            DECLARE @UserUID INT = (SELECT TOP 1 UserUID FROM Chars WHERE CharID = @CharID)
```

[For more clarification try this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nse7Kgm6K3I)

Comment: Problem is in your sub queries so you may change accordingly if the above don't meet your solution try this given below. 
        DECLARE @CharID INT = (SELECT TOP 1CharID FROM inserted)

Comment: Made the edits and still seem to be having the problem

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcAKLo-cb0c
try this.
I m pretty sure this will help you more

Answer (score 0):

The issue only happens with some players it seems this stored procedure is the error

```
USE [PS_GameData]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_Save_Char_Quest_Add_E]    Script Date: 13/03/2019 18:02:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER Proc [dbo].[usp_Save_Char_Quest_Add_E]

@CharID int,
@QuestID int,
@Delay smallint = Null,
@Count1 tinyint = Null,
@Count2 tinyint = Null,
@Count3 tinyint = Null

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO CharQuests(CharID,QuestID,[Delay],Count1,Count2,Count3) VALUES(@CharID,@QuestID,@Delay,@Count1,@Count2,@Count3)

IF(@@ERROR = 0)
BEGIN
    RETURN 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    RETURN -1
END

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```